# Is it possible to connect multiple flutter projects with one firebase database?

Tags: firebase, flutter

How many flutter project can connect with one firebase database?
There are 4 members working with one firebase database.
But flutter projects are different.
Is it possible to connect it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create many app base on a project firebase.

You can add Flutter project (Android/IOS/Web Application) on Firebase setting.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9326094?hl=en